# FlowRow with chips in the between of fields in jetpack

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, row

I have a problem with flowRow with chips which contains text field and this field must be between two field, at the and of row it must contain additional box with icons, and to archive this, I'm using weight(1f) modifier.
But then the input text is big, code throw exception
IllegalArgumentException: maxWidth(714) must be >= than minWidth(727)

What I need to achieve in the code, to manage my exception.
The main idea is to write some text, on enter create chip. But Field must contain dropdown menu, because I have suggestion search on input.

```
Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.Top,
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween) {
 Box( // Icon)
  ExposedDropdownMenuBox(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f), expanded = expanded)) {
    FlowRow(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(1f)) {chips.forEachIndexed { index, email -> //....}
      BasicTextField(value = currentInput,
                     singleLine = false,
                     modifier = Modifier
                                .weight(1f) ///I think a problem is in this
                                .menuAnchor()
                    )
               }
    }
  Box(modifier = Modifier.width(50.dp)
     ) {
        Row(modifier = Modifier.height(24.dp))
            {
             Icon()
             }
        }
}
```

[image]

[image]